# how do I read the request data on deno

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, post, deno

How can i read the request data on a post request on deno? I can't find anything in the req object

```js
for await (const req of s) {
  //             ^ that req object
  if(req.url === '/update' && method == 'POST') console.log(req) // this is where I need the data
}
```

Comment: See `ServerRequest.method` at the type docs: https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std@0.103.0/http/server.ts#ServerRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you actually use the correct library, but this is an example of it working:

```js
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.103.0/http/server.ts";
import { readAll } from "https://deno.land/std@0.103.0/io/util.ts";

const server = serve({ port: 8080 });
console.log(`HTTP webserver running.  Access it at:  http://localhost:8080/`);

for await (const req of server) {
  if (req.url === "/update" && req.method === "POST") {
    console.log("Body:", new TextDecoder().decode(await readAll(req.body)));
  }

  req.respond({ status: 200, body: "Welcome to my server" });
}
```

Comment: it's working! but I don't need to import anything else except serve